# ListBoxField styling from CMS

Tags: silverstripe

I've used `ListBoxField` before and it works awesomely in the CMS however when I've added it to my site it's quite basic. Is there any simple way to add the CSS / JavaScript to page on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't remember if ListBoxField uses chosen or not but check it out at https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. It offers a pretty similar experience. You should be able to include chosen js and css files on the front end and then follow the documentation to get it going.

Comment: Seems there is a ready-to-use module: http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/muskie9/silverstripe-chosen-dropdown